# How can i move a subview to another view as its subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have multiple views (A,B,C,D). B and C are subviews to A and D is a subview to B.

How can I move the view D from B to C? I.e i want D's superview to go from B to C.

I have tried

```
[D removeFromSuperview];
 D.frame = (CGRect){10,10,100,100};
[C addSubviews:D];
```

Comment: It's true, but third line is `[C addSubview:D];`.

Comment: Then what is the problem you have faced?

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that since any `UIView` can have only one superview, `removeFromSuperview` is superfluous

Answer (score 0):

You wrote addSubviews instead of addSubview...

```
[D removeFromSuperview];
D.frame = (CGRect){10,10,100,100};
[C addSubview:D];
```